# Filling graph with colour

Tags: vba

I want to format series on my graph, I registered macro:

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(146, 208, 80)
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With
```

and then I put it into my code:

```
        With Wykres
            .ShowLegendFieldButtons = False
            .ShowValueFieldButtons = False
            .ShowAxisFieldButtons = False
            .ShowAllFieldButtons = False
            .Legend.Delete
            .ChartStyle = 340
            .SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
            .ChartTitle.Text = "Ilość w podziale na województwa"
            .SetElement (msoElementDataLabelOutSideEnd)
            .Parent.RoundedCorners = True
            .ChartArea.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = KolorUzytkownika
            .FullSeriesCollection.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = KolorUzytkownika
        End With
```

but something is wrong with the last line of my code. I received message: "Object doesn't support this property or method". I use late binding but I guess it doesn't matter here.

Comment: The properties listed for `FullSeriesCollection` objects in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/fullseriescollection-object-excel) doesn't include a `Format` property. It is a collection - so you will probably need to iterate through it item by item, changing the format of each.

Comment: Your recorded macro says `FullSeriesCollection(1)` which means series 1 of the series collection, but you only inserted `FullSeriesCollection` into your main code, which doesn't specify a series to format.

Answer (score 6):

`.FullSeriesCollection` is of type `Collection`. You can't access/modify a property of type `Series` for `Collection` type. Hence the error.

[image]

You need to first access the item from the collection and then all the public properties and methods of that item's type become accessible.

`.FullSeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

This will loop through and format all series on chart belonging to 1st `ChartObject` on 1st `Worksheet`. In your case, replace `Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(1).Chart` with `Wykres`:

```
Sub formatChartSeries()

    Dim s

    For Each s In Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection
        s.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(146, 208, 80) 'format fill / marker
        s.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(146, 208, 80) 'format border / line
    Next s

End Sub
```

Above solution is compatible with Excel 2010 which doesn't support `FullSeriesCollection`.